# Cannot read property 'split' of null returns NaN

Tags: javascript

i have made this function that takes value from the count of words there are in a string and multiplies it from a custom price. Both values are taken from input fields. However it gets me an error by calling this function "NaN". Can you spot the problem here?

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Telegramma</title>

  <script>
  var string = document.getElementById("text");
  var words = new Number (string.split(" ").length);
  var price = new Number (document.getElementById("price").value);

  function showPrice(){
  var total = new Number (words * price);
   document.getElementById("showPrice").innerHTML = total;
}
  </script>

 </head>


 </body>

</html>
```

```html
<body>
Text:<input id = "text" type = "text"/>
Price per a word &euro;<input id = "price" min="0.01" step="0.01" type = "number" />

<button onclick = "showPrice()">Get the full price</button>

<p id = "showPrice"> </p>
```

Comment: Put the `script` tag after `body` tag.

Comment: Where the script appears is not as important as the code being correct. The declarations and initializations for `string`, `words`, and `price` should be **inside** the function, not outside. With that change, the `<script>` can be anywhere.

Comment: Also there's no reason to put the multiplication inside a call to the Number constructor. Just `var total = words * price;` is fine.

Comment: thank you, but now it tells me string.split is not a function, something is wrong with my syntax

Comment: @RalfsR `string` is an element, not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the `string`, `words` and `price` variables in the showPrice() function. Your code never assigns these values.

Additionally, this line

```
var string = document.getElementById("text");
```

assigns the input element instead of the content. You need to use

```
var string = document.getElementById("text").value;
```

to get the desired result.

Here is a full code example:

```
function showPrice(){
  var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
  var words = new Number (text.split(" ").length);
  var price = new Number (document.getElementById("price").value);
  var total = new Number (words * price);
  document.getElementById("showPrice").innerHTML = total;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMmYgd)

Answer (score 0):

That is because when your script is executing, the content in not created, yet. Put all your script after all content just before `body` close tag. Or execute everything on body load event.